# What kind of tests to be performed when new suse linux OS is installed into the server

Tags: linux, server

In our company we have installed new open source suse linux(openSUSE Leap 15.0 x86-64) and configured Web,app and other required applications and also oracle DB is installed on the newly configured suse linux server.

From testing perspective what kind of tests need to be performed to make sure everything is working as expected in free open source suse linux (previously used was suse paid version)

Comment: What are you asking?  How to test Suse?  What do you care about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on many things. Enterprise applications are normally executed within containers (for example application servers) which introduce certain abstraction for the app so that it does not care much of which OS it is running in. However there are still certain OS-specific points which might matter (e.g. file path specification).

Another important thing to consider is the OS that used to host your app before.

Anyway (if you have limited budget - otherwise it is better to perform full regression) I would recommend to test at least the cases which cover IO like

- read/write files
- privileges issues
- read/write over the network

It also makes sense to verify that you do not have performance degradation.